# DTS Package sql job

Tags: dts

Ive never used sql jobs or dts.

What does..

```
N'DTSRun /~Z0xB6A63469D036090E592289E9BB069DBBB66DA8B3F00BB110255F2D64DD7346100CB714C2190C187070FAAF5BA84AB86B45D9EDCF423D9EE4FD4440C56ED3BB66F3337538BBC796E1A2AA15E8A78ED222DED7F01A55CF9AB025F8CB97E387FB129E9C77A6602918F64627B07CD005ED09569E30567F5AF1991346894A13CB2D7083C04A03AD842CF0C18665 '
```

mean?
where do i find the code to change this routine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an encrypted `DtsRun` Command

With `DTSRun` is also possible run ecrypted command line (as in your case)

You have to decypt the command to be able to locate your package

anyway the below are the step to decrypt it

1. Copy the DTSRun command line from the job step (including the very long encrypted string!)
2. Open a Windows Command Line Window and paste the command into it.
3. Add /!X and /!C to the end of the DTSRun command. (/!X says do not run and /!C says copy results into clipboard)
4. Execute the command. (You should see DTSRun: Loading … and DTSRun: Executing …. as is displayed below and the cleartext parameters should now be in your paste buffer)
   more info about `DtsRun` utility

[image]

more info at the below link

[Decrypting the encrypted DTSRun /~Z command-line parameters](http://bisqlserver.rdacorp.com/2008/08/decrypting-encrypted-dtsrun-z-command.html)

Comment: i paste into notepad after and get...DTSRun /S "(local)" /N "Smarts Order Import [Multi Schedule]" /E /!X /!C

Comment: whats this mean, where is the Smart Order Import program so i can change it?

Comment: what ever is after {/[~]N package_name } is the package name. You should be able to find it under storage package.
more info at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966389.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The `/~Z` in front of that blob means that the command line parameters are [encrypted using SQL Server 2000 encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224467%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

In order to see what the actual command line parameters are, run this command:

```
DTSRun /~Z0xB6A63469D0... /!X /!C
```

Which will put the decrypted command in your clipboard for you to paste and view somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

This is a encrypted form of dts, and is used to send to client, so that he could run dts on his own machine. Just copy that string to command prompt and press enter!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server includes a utility called `DTSRUNUI.exe`. This application can be run from a command line or by just simply double clicking on the application file and  can be found in the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn
```

or wherever you installed the SQL Server tools.  The following screen comes up when you launch this program.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the DTS package file, you can open and import (and then modify) DTS packages from within SQL Server 2008, but you will need to install a runtime - see "Installing Run-time Support for SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440.aspx .

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.